# Ubuntu 15.10 messed graphics after latest update

Tags: unity, updates, launcher, 15.10, icons

After latest Ubuntu auto-update, my whole system is messed up but most important one for me is strange icons. The icons are pixelated in launcher and System settings. There is some kind of black border around icons when hovering them too.

Here is my history.log from latest update:

```
$ tail -n55 /var/log/apt/history.log

Start-Date: 2016-02-09  00:32:24
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.92'
Upgrade: libavformat-ffmpeg56:amd64 (2.7.5-0ubuntu0.15.10.1, 2.7.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1), qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects:amd64 (5.4.2-1ubuntu2, 5.5.1-1ubuntu1~wily1~test1), libswresample-ffmpeg1:amd64 (2.7.5-0ubuntu0.15.10.1, 2.7.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1), libepoxy0:amd64 (1.2-1, 1.3.1-1~ubuntu15.10~ppa1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (48.0.2564.97-1, 48.0.2564.103-1), libdecoration0:amd64 (0.9.12.2+15.10.20151015-0ubuntu1, 0.9.12.2+15.10.20151202-0ubuntu1), qml-module-qtfeedback:amd64 (5.0~git20130529-0ubuntu11, 5.0~git20130529-0ubuntu12~wily1~test2), compiz-gnome:amd64 (0.9.12.2+15.10.20151015-0ubuntu1, 0.9.12.2+15.10.20151202-0ubuntu1), unity:amd64 (7.3.2+15.10.20151016-0ubuntu1, 7.3.3+15.10.20151203-0ubuntu1), qml-module-qt-labs-settings:amd64 (5.4.2-1ubuntu6, 5.5.1-2ubuntu1~wily1~test2), libunity-core-6.0-9:amd64 (7.3.2+15.10.20151016-0ubuntu1, 7.3.3+15.10.20151203-0ubuntu1), compiz-core:amd64 (0.9.12.2+15.10.20151015-0ubuntu1, 0.9.12.2+15.10.20151202-0ubuntu1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:amd64 (15.10.14.2, 15.10.14.3), libqt5feedback5:amd64 (5.0~git20130529-0ubuntu11, 5.0~git20130529-0ubuntu12~wily1~test2), libcompizconfig0:amd64 (0.9.12.2+15.10.20151015-0ubuntu1, 0.9.12.2+15.10.20151202-0ubuntu1), unity-services:amd64 (7.3.2+15.10.20151016-0ubuntu1, 7.3.3+15.10.20151203-0ubuntu1), libepoxy-dev:amd64 (1.2-1, 1.3.1-1~ubuntu15.10~ppa1), libpostproc-ffmpeg53:amd64 (2.7.5-0ubuntu0.15.10.1, 2.7.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1), libqt5test5:amd64 (5.4.2+dfsg-2ubuntu9, 5.5.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1~wily1~test1), unity-schemas:amd64 (7.3.2+15.10.20151016-0ubuntu1, 7.3.3+15.10.20151203-0ubuntu1), libswscale-ffmpeg3:amd64 (2.7.5-0ubuntu0.15.10.1, 2.7.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1), qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin:amd64 (5.4.2-1ubuntu6, 5.5.1-2ubuntu1~wily1~test2), libqt5x11extras5:amd64 (5.4.2-2build1, 5.5.1-1), python3-distupgrade:amd64 (15.10.14.2, 15.10.14.3), qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin:amd64 (5.4.2-1ubuntu6, 5.5.1-2ubuntu1~wily1~test2), compiz-plugins-default:amd64 (0.9.12.2+15.10.20151015-0ubuntu1, 0.9.12.2+15.10.20151202-0ubuntu1), lightdm:amd64 (1.16.6-0ubuntu1, 1.16.7-0ubuntu1), liblightdm-gobject-1-0:amd64 (1.16.6-0ubuntu1, 1.16.7-0ubuntu1), libavcodec-extra:amd64 (2.7.5-0ubuntu0.15.10.1, 2.7.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1), libavutil-ffmpeg54:amd64 (2.7.5-0ubuntu0.15.10.1, 2.7.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (15.10.14.2, 15.10.14.3), qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel:amd64 (5.4.2-1ubuntu6, 5.5.1-2ubuntu1~wily1~test2), libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56:amd64 (2.7.5-0ubuntu0.15.10.1, 2.7.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1), qtdeclarative5-qtfeedback-plugin:amd64 (5.0~git20130529-0ubuntu11, 5.0~git20130529-0ubuntu12~wily1~test2), libgsettings-qt1:amd64 (0.1+14.10.20140807-0ubuntu6~gcc5.1, 0.1+14.10.20140807-0ubuntu6~wily1~qt551~1~gcc5.2)
End-Date: 2016-02-09  00:33:47
```

Does anyone know what is it up to? This makes me disable auto-update for ubuntu forever. Here is a picture of how it looks like (mouse over):

[Strange black border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArsmI.png)

There is also an error with Unity Tweak tool. I can't open it and I get error at the start with following message:

```
com.canonical.unity.webapps
In order to work properly, Unity Tweak Tool recommends you install the necessary packages
```

But when I try to install the package over `unity-webapps-service` I got this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-webapps-service : Depends: webapp-container
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And then it goes on for webapp-container (missing another dependencies etc.).

Log files:
[term.log](https://gist.github.com/dn5/95f1715883665f13fa77)

```
[x0rg.log](https://gist.github.com/dn5/1eb740a338db1f0f0add)




Output of ps w/ grep:

 $ ps -A | grep unity
 1955 ?        00:00:01 unity-settings-
 1965 ?        00:00:42 unity-panel-ser
 3342 ?        00:00:00 unity-scope-hom
 3354 ?        00:00:01 unity-scope-loa
 3355 ?        00:00:00 unity-files-dae
```

Any advices? Thanks.

Comment: Please post your /var/log/apt/term.log

Comment: Are You using Skylake Intel HD 530? I encounter similar issues with exactly this update.

Comment: @mdeslaur I've edited the post at the bottom with term.log and some more info.

Comment: @Hartmut No I don't. Thanks for the info tho.